# C++ I can't use an fstream variable to save to a file

Tags: c++, fstream

can anyone recognize mistake of using fstream variable fFile here? because at function Save() writing to disk process (by function WriteTo()) is always fail.
But if I declare new local fstream variable instead of fFile, save is ok.
(please see part of the code below)

thank you

---

```
class CardCollection{
public:
    CardCollection();
    int Open(const char filename[]);    
    void Close();   
    void Close();   
int NumCards()const;    
void ReportStatus()const;   
void AddCards();    
void DeleteCard(int cardnum);   
void ShowCard(int cardnum)const;    
void ChangeCard(int cardnum);   
void DoFind();  
void DoFindAgain(); 
void DoView();
private:
int GetField(int anyallowed);   
void Load();    
int fNumCards;
char *fFileName;    
std::fstream fFile;
DynamicArray fStore;
char *fFindString;
int fFindPos;
int fSearchField;
};



int CardCollection::Open(const char filename[])
{
    //Keep copy of filename
fFileName = new char[strlen(filename)+1];
strcpy(fFileName, filename);

fFile.open(fFileName, std::ios::out | std::ios::in);
if(!fFile.good())
    return -1;
Load();
return 0;
}

void CardCollection::Save()
{
for(int i = fNumCards ; i > 0; i--){
    RefCard *r = (RefCard*) fStore.Nth(i);
    r->WriteTo(fFile);      // If I declare a new fstream here
                    // instead of using fFile, save is ok
}
if(fFile.good()){
    std::cout << "Saving completed";
}
else{
    std::cout << "Saving error";
}
}
```

Comment: Did you call `Open` before `Save`? Did it succeed?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use `std::string` for strings, instead of pointers? (Like for example `fFileName`.) The same with `bool`, why not use it for example as the return of the `Open` function?

Comment: Did you make sure that `filename` and `fFileName` are correct?

Comment: No mistake in the code here. The mistake is somewhere else (like probably inside `Open` or `Save`).

Comment: When has `<!-- language: c++ -->` been a comment in C++?

Comment: Your `Open` function calls `Load`, which probably moves your file pointer to the end.  Do you need to rewind the file pointer back to the beginning when saving?

Comment: Show us where you call `Save`

Comment: For reading, open with ios::in, close after you are done. For writing, open with ios::out, close after you are done. Alternatively, open once with in|out, do seek to the beginning before each read and write

Comment: @Domi yes i call Open() before Save().

Comment: actually this code is from a tutorial (http://www.uow.edu.au/~/nabg/ABC/ABC.html) exclude function save(). i think calling sequence is correct already and the error maybe in function save() that i made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm willing to bet that you don't reset the `fstream` after you have loaded the data.

Add this to the beginning of Save

```
fFile.clear();
fFile.seekp(0);
```

Comment: Given the use, he probably shouldn't keep the file open all this time anyway.  The best solution would be to open the file (uniquely for input) in Load, and to open it again (this time only for output) in Save.

Comment: @JamesKanze This is true. In fact there appear to be any number of data members of `CardCollection` that shouldn't be there. But learning OOP is another task.

Comment: yes it solve by add:

fFile.clear();
fFile.seekp(0);

@john thank you